# Tuning controllers in dual-loop control with feed-forward and decoupling signals

Tags: control, control-system, pid-controller, dsp

What would be the best step-by-step approach to tune PI controllers in a dual-loop control with decoupling and feed-forward signals?

[image]

I am trying to tune both the voltage and current controller in DSP F28379D using MATLAB Simulink, but my PI controller outputs' end up quickly in saturation and changing gains seems to have no effect. I suspect this is because of the feed-forward and decoupling signals.

Even if I set all the gains initially to zero (and follow [this](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/174/31327) guide), the output is not zero, again because of the feed-forward and decoupling signals.

I am trying to control a three-phase inverter with an LC filter in a stand-alone application. The input signal is an output phase voltage reference.

Comment: Depends on what you’re trying to control. PI controllers can make a system go unstable regardless of gains if the system you’re controlling has a double integrator.

Comment: If all Ki * Kp = 0 then find out where the offset comes from that integrates to saturation including initial conditions

Comment: **1** Please add much more details about the plant (3 phase inverter) and how it is connected to controller. **2** Is the inverter model in Simulink a *small signal* model ? **3** is the inverter control ON-OFF control ? How is PI out put converted to ON-OFF in that case ?